# Export source code comments to the WSDL using CXF and maven?

Tags: java, web-services, maven, wsdl, cxf

Like the title says: Is it possible to export my javadoc comments for web service method parameters into the wsdl? We're using CXF and the java2ws goal with maven to generate the wsdl from source code.

Comment: Not sure about JAXWS and params, but with JAXRS you can annotate *methods* with `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.Description` and it shows up in the generated WADL.

Comment: Hm, there's a `@WSDLDocumentation` annotation but that's not good enough. If there's a method with more than one or two parameters or a constructor that has to be used to create the parameters one description for the entire method won't be enough. I'd like to have the javadocs available so the developer using the webservice knows how to build the objects that the service expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `@WSDLDocumentationCollection` annotation to attach multiple `@WSDLDocumentation` annotations to a single method (with different placements) but you can't use this to go much deeper than placing documentation on single operations of a port, because that's where it ceases to be a WSDL problem and becomes an XSD problem. XSD documentation would be handled by an annotation at the JAXB level, except that no such annotation exists; the schema generated won't contain `<xs:documentation>` elements. (When *starting* from a schema, documentation comments can be generated as Javadoc, but the reverse direction doesn't happen as Javadoc comments aren't retained in Java class files.)