# Regenerate original xsd:annotations with cxf-codegen-plugin

Tags: maven, cxf, wsdl2java, cxf-codegen-plugin

I have an XSD with some complex types. All the types are annotated with xsd:annotation and documentation. I am using contract first approach. The WSDL is designed by someone else so I can't change it. My problem is that CXF generated WSDL does not contains original xsd:annotation nodes because they are lost during the cxf-codegen-plugin generation phase. Is there any way I can maintain those nodes?

Comment: Check related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8534906/3656963

Comment: So, according to that it is not possible?